# Many-to-many relation in loopback with different relation property name

Tags: loopback

I've the following models:

- `Account`
- `Page`
- `AccountPage`

the `AccountPage` is a "through" model, here are my configurations for those models

**AccountPage.json**

```
{
  "name": "AccountPage",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "subscriptionDate": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "subscriber": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Account",
      "foreignKey": "subscriberId"
    },
    "page": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Page",
      "foreignKey": "pageId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**Page.json**

```
{
  "name": "Page",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": 
    "subscribers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Account",
      "foreignKey": "subscriberId",
      "through": "AccountPage",
      "keyThrough": "pageId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**Account.json**

```
{
  "name": "Account",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "pages": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Page",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "through": "AccountPage",
      "keyThrough": "subscriberId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

When I access GET **/Pages/{id}/subscribers**, I got

> "Relation \"account\" is not defined for AccountPage model"

If I change `"subscriber"` relation name in `AccountPage.json` to `"account"` it works ok, is this a bug or am I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was misconfiguring the `foreignKey` and `keyThrough` in `Page`, and `Account` models. The foreignKey of `Account` relation in the `Page` model should have `foreigKey` of pageId, as according to the documentation "Specify custom foreignKey (for *this* model) on the related model" so it should be pageId not `subscriberId`.

So `Page` model relation will be (**Page.json**):

```
"subscribers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Account",
      "foreignKey": "pageId",
      "through": "AccountPage",
      "keyThrough": "subscriberId"
    }
```

and `Account` model relation will be (**Account.json**):

```
"pages": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Page",
      "foreignKey": "subscriberId",
      "through": "AccountPage",
      "keyThrough": "pageId"
    }
```

Now it is working fine